# Elasticsearch how to query a property of type docutment which should contain some nested property

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elasticsearch-6

Hi I would like to get the documents from ES6 which contains a property of type object with some searched property.
Document structure looks like:

```
{
   "ico": 46594523,
   "contacts": {
          "phones": null,
          "emails": [
                 "aaa@aaa.aa"
          ]
   },
   "name": "aaaaaaaaa"
   }
},
```

and I would like to search all documents which have field contacts.emails.
This query works with ES2 but does not work with ES6. What is wrong with it?

```
{
    "query": 
    {
        "exists": {"field": "contacts.emails"}
    }
}
```

I need to search in contacts object properties https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html

Comment: Is it actually a `nested` property in the mapping?

Comment: No this is not nested type.

Comment: Your query looks correct. What does your mapping and your full query look like?

Comment: This is the mapping of contacts property:

       ```"contacts": {
          "properties": {
            "emails": {
              "index": false,
              "type": "text"
            },
            "domains": {
              "index": false,
              "type": "text"
            },
            "phones": {
              "index": false,
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },```
query can be as simple as I wrote above but does not work.

Comment: Can be the problem in **index: false** mapping?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in mapping which says the contacts.emails is not indexed.

Comment: Yes, if your mapping sets `"index": "false"` then it will not be put into the inverted index. So to Elasticsearch, it doesn't "exist".